# Setting AngularJS global values for accessing and setting across controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have been experimenting with AngularJS values, and wish to store a global value for accessing and setting in different controllers.

So I have been trying out with the value approach like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('globalValue', 0);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'globalValue', function($scope, $rootScope, globalValue) {
    $scope.updateValue = function() {
        globalValue++;
    };    
}]);

app.controller('myCtrlB', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'globalValue', function($scope, $rootScope, globalValue) {
        $scope.someValueB=globalValue;

}]);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfxy5hs1/2/)

This is not working as I thought it might, so in my fiddle, when clicking the button to increment my 'global', the scope property in myCtrlB does not change.

I have clearly gone about this the wrong way, have I totally misunderstood how to use value()'s here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using angular.constant()?

Comment: @user1518802 constant would work as well though it's a bit of a misnomer since the value doesn't remain constant over time.  In functional terms it would work fine though since constant is also just a provider with less restrictions than .value https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers The problem is still the same though because of the value being assigned rather than a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work basically you need an object so both controllers are pointing at the same object and some property of that object is changed.  Otherwise you are assigning the initial value of globalValue to some local variable but it's not a reference.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('globalValue', {counter:0});

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'globalValue', function($scope, $rootScope, globalValue) {
    $scope.updateValue = function() {
        globalValue.counter++;
    };    
}]);

app.controller('myCtrlB', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'globalValue', function($scope, $rootScope, globalValue) {
        $scope.someValueB=globalValue;

}]);
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfxy5hs1/3/

Comment: Ok so how does $scope.someValueB in myCtrB resolve to globalValue.counter? I was expecting that line to read $scope.someValueB=globalValue.counter; What if there were multiple properties set in that globalValue object in the app.value() call?

Comment: @mindparse in the view that uses myCtrlB I just updated the binding to point to the specific property of the object defined with the provider/value definition.  Any time that you assign a string or a primitive (anything that's not an object) you are really making a copy of the value.  In JS if you assign an object you are setting a new pointer to point to the same object, so when you change properties of that object both pointers are pointing at the same object.

Comment: Doh I overlooked {{someValueB.counter}} in your version of the view! Makes sense now, thanks!